# How to display the result with temple jinjia2 or others?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

```
import sqlite3,os
db=r'F:\workspace\china\data\china.sqlite'
con=sqlite3.connect(db)
cur=con.cursor()
res=cur.execute('select 代码,所属行业,注册资本,雇员人数,管理人员人数 from profile limit 20').fetchall()
for row in res:
    print(row)
```

('600000', '银行', '187亿', 39340.0, 30.0)
('600004', '民航机场', '11.5亿', 4499.0, 23.0)
('600005', '钢铁行业', '101亿', 38857.0, 24.0)
('600006', '汽车行业', '20.0亿', 10290.0, 20.0)
('600007', '房地产', '10.1亿', 2332.0, 19.0)
('600008', '公用事业', '22.0亿', 6515.0, 20.0)
('600009', '民航机场', '19.3亿', 5472.0, 18.0)
('600010', '钢铁行业', '80.0亿', 31389.0, 19.0)
('600011', '电力行业', '141亿', 37729.0, 29.0)
('600012', '高速公路', '16.6亿', 2106.0, 14.0)
('600015', '银行', '89.0亿', 25200.0, 34.0)
('600016', '银行', '340亿', 54927.0, 32.0)
('600017', '港口水运', '30.8亿', 5340.0, 21.0)
('600018', '港口水运', '228亿', 19842.0, 20.0)
('600019', '钢铁行业', '165亿', 37487.0, 23.0)
('600020', '高速公路', '22.5亿', 2959.0, 32.0)
('600021', '电力行业', '21.4亿', 6673.0, 22.0)
('600022', '钢铁行业', '64.4亿', 31738.0, 20.0)
('600023', '电力行业', '118亿', 10142.0, 14.0)
('600026', '港口水运', '34.0亿', 7536.0, 21.0)

Now i want to display the output in html table.

```
html_str='<table border=1>'
for row in res:
    html_str=html_str+'<tr>'
    for col in row:
        html_str=html_str+'<td>'+str(col)
        html_str=html_str+'</td>'
    html_str=html_str+'</tr>'

html_str=html_str+'</table>'
myhtml=open('f:\\test.html','w')
myhtml.write(html_str)
myhtml.close()
os.system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" f:\\test.html')
```

I want to improve my code
1.to simplify the creation of html file.
2.it is stupid to open the test.html file with
`os.system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" f:\\test.html')`

How can i display it with temple jinjia2 more elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a template with [`jinja2.Template`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template):

```
import jinja2

template = jinja2.Template('''
<table border=1>
{% for row in res %}
    <tr>
    {% for col in row -%}
        <td>{{ col|replace('\s', ':1,7>') }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
''')
```

Render the template with [`jinja2.Template.render`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template.render) (with `res` passed), then write it to file:

```
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(template.render(res=res))
```

To open the file in browser, use [`webbrowser.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) (It will use the default web browser):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('test.html')
```